# Generator cannot be in a Closure

Tags: php, closures, generator, anonymous-function

I'm creating a class that uses a generator to return values when a particular method is called, something like:

```
class test {
    protected $generator;

    private function getValueGenerator() {
        yield from [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->generator = $this->getValueGenerator();
    }

    public function getValue() {
        while($this->generator->valid()) {
            $latitude = $this->generator->current();
            $this->generator->next();
            return $latitude;
        }
        throw new RangeException('End of line');
    }
}

$line = new test();

try {
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
        echo $line->getValue();
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Which works perfectly well when the generator is defined as a method within the class itself.... but I want to make this more dynamic, and use a closure as the generator, something like:

```
class test {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->generator = function() {
            yield from [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run this, I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Closure::valid()

in the call to `getValue()`

Can anybody explain the actual logic of why I can't call the generator this way? And how I might be able to use a closure rather than a hard-coded generator function?

Comment: You initialize the field to a closure, but you want the result of invoking the closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first example you invoke the method, creating the generator:

```
$this->generator = $this->getValueGenerator();
```

In the second you do *not* invoke it, so it's merely a closure:

```
$this->generator = function() {
    yield from [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
};
```

Invoking that closure should create the generator (PHP 7 if you don't want to assign an intermediate variable):

```
$this->generator = (function() {
    yield from [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
})();
```

Comment: Bingo! Although the PHP7 "approach" doesn't seem to work (even with additional `{}` braces), but using an intermediate variable so that the closure is invokable works. Thanks!